# Get unique value of field array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array like this

```
[{
  Item: pen,
  Color: blue,
  Brand: cello
},{
  Item: pen,
  Color: red,
  Brand: cello
},{
  Item: pen,
  Color: blue,
  Brand: cello
}]
```

I want the result to be like

```
[{
  Item: pen,
  Brand: cello
}]
```

I need to remove one attribute "Color" from the array and get unique value. Could some one help me how to achieve this output?

Answer (score 1):

you can keep a new empty array, iterate over the original array delete color key from each object and push it to new array if it is not already present in the new array.

```js
var arr = [{Item: 'pen', Color: 'blue', Brand: 'cello'}, {Item: 'pen', Color: 'red', Brand: 'cello'}, {Item: 'pen', Color: 'blue', Brand: 'cello'}];

var newArr = [];
arr.forEach(x => {
   delete x.Color
   for(var i=0; i<newArr.length; i++)
      if(newArr[i].Item === x.Item && newArr[i].Brand === x.Brand)
         return;
   newArr.push(x);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and `array#some`. Use `delete` to remove `Color` property from object.

```js
var arr = [{ Item: 'pen',Color: 'blue',Brand: 'cello'},{Item: 'pen',Color: 'red',Brand: 'cello'},{Item: 'pen',Color: 'blue',Brand: 'cello'}];


var uniq = arr.reduce(function(u, o1){
  delete o1.Color;
  var isExist = u.some(function(o2){
    return o2.Item === o1.Item && o2.Brand === o1.Brand;
  });
  if(!isExist)
    u.push(o1);
  return u;
},[]); 

console.log(uniq);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over each object in the array and assign its values to a new object. This new object, can have the color key deleted and pushed to a different array.

```js
var array = [{
  Item: 'pen',
  Color: 'blue',
  Brand: 'cello'
},{
  Item: 'pen',
  Color: 'red',
  Brand: 'cello'
},{
  Item: 'pen',
  Color: 'blue',
  Brand: 'cello'
}];

const newArray = [];
array.map(obj => {
  let newObject = Object.assign({}, obj); 
  delete newObject.Color;
  if(newArray.length) {
    newArray.map(newObj => {
      if(newObj.Item !== newObject.item && newObj.Brand !== newObject.Brand) {
        newArray.push(newObject);
      }
    });
  } else {
    newArray.push(newObject);
  }
});

console.log(array);
console.log(newArray);
```